# Cannot clone input fields from third time onwards in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to clone html inputs without values. I tried as below:

```
$(function() {
        var unique_id = 0;
        $('.click').on('click', function() {
            unique_id++;

            $('#parentSection').clone().insertAfter('#parentSection')
                .find("input, select")
                .val('')
                .each(function(){
                    $(this).attr("id",$(this).attr("id")+"_"+(unique_id));
                    $(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name")+"_"+(unique_id));
                    var fieldName = $(this).attr('name');
                    $(this).siblings().attr('for', fieldName);
                })
        });
    });
<div id="parentSection">
   <div class="control-group">
            <label for="order">Order</label>
            <input name="order" id="order" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <button type="button" class="click">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I clicked the add button for third time, it will not clone and not even execute this function without generating any errors. So where could I get wrong and how should I correct it?

Comment: Post your html code also for better understanding of the problem

Comment: I have added my html as well @Abhishek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the form elements like input, select field within row under parentSection, after click on add more get the clone of first row and append to end of div 'parentSection'.

like.

```js
jQuery(function($){
var unique_id = 1;
 jQuery('.click').on('click', function(){
  $("#parentSection .row:first").clone().find("input,select").each(function() {

  /*In this case, Generally for name attr used in array format like - input[0][name1], input[1][name2] etc
  for array you can use like.
  this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/,function(str,p1){return '[' + (parseInt(p1,10)+unique_id) + ']'});
  */

  this.name = $(this).attr("name")+"_"+unique_id; //make name unique of new row
  this.id = $(this).attr("id")+"_"+unique_id; // make id unique of new row
  this.value = '';  //male value empty of new row
  }).end().appendTo("#parentSection").find('.delete_row').show();

  unique_id++;


  //Delete current row on click of delete_row button
  jQuery('.delete_row').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery(this).parent().remove();

  });

 });
});
```

```html
 

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  

  <div id="parentSection">
   <div class="control-group row">
            <label for="order">Order</label>
            <input name="order" id="order" type="text">
   <a class="delete_row" style="display:none">Delete Row </a>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <button type="button" class="click">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Shivendra Singh. It was helpful. But that jquery was not executed after ` $("#parentSection .row:first").clone().find("input,select").each(function() {` line in my code. I have updated my problem with html code as well.

Comment: That issue was because of the missing row class in my html.

Comment: Thank you very much @Shivendra Singh. Now I am having problem in cloning

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275459/clone-outer-div-and-inner-div-separately-using-jquery     @Shivendra Singh